# how in python Remove files with .log Extension

Tags: python, centos7

How can I list all file of a directory in Python and remove them by .log?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/home/m110/public_html/ts/'):
print(files)

output1281.log
output1020.log
log3.log
mem.py
output1087.log
bunker3.py
output1248.log
output1311.log
output1099.log
output1261.log
output1282.log
output1213.log
log43.log
output1291.log
output1095.log
output1209.log
usr.txt
output1210.log
log7.log
output1042.log
attack.py
output1032.log
output1318.log
```

i run this code in Centos7 but i just need list file with .log file extension for delete times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
files= next(os.walk(r'/home/m110/public_html/ts/'))[2]
for filename in files:
    ex=filename.split(".")[-1]
    if ex=='log':
       #print ex
       os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `os`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/m110/public_html/ts/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            os.remove(root +  '/' + file)
```

In Python 3+, you can use `pathlib`:

```
paths = pathlib.Path('/home/m110/public_html/ts/').glob('*.log')
for path in paths:
    path.unlink()
```

Comment: @daneshkarimi if you want to print the files, you can do:
paths = list(pathlib.Path('/home/m110/public_html/ts/').glob('*.log'))
print(paths)

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished by calling `rm *.log` in the bash as well, but for python:

```
import os
from glob import glob
log_file_list = glob('folder/*.log')
for file in log_file_list:
    os.remove(file)
```

This is only works for files in the top level of a folder.

[Glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) does pathname pattern matching as the unix bash does, [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) removes a file with a given path.

If you want to include subfolders, you can set the `recursive=True` flag and change the search expression like so:

```
import os
from glob import glob
log_file_list = glob('folder/**/*.log', recursive=True)
for file in log_file_list:
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `os` to remove the file. You can use the `unlink` method on the Path object directly, which removes the file or link.

Comment: @DiegoMoraCespedes cool, thanks for the hint. I was not aware of this feature.